# Check if html element is supported

Tags: javascript, html, browser-detection

How to check if html element is supported, [**datalist**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/datalist) for example? MDC says it is supoorted only in Opera and FireFox.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
if ('options' in document.createElement('datalist')) {
    // supported!
}
```

http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html#datalist

Answer (score 1):

If someone needs to check for support of other HTML5 elements this could also be used.

https://github.com/ryanmorr/is-element-supported

From http://ryanmorr.com/determine-html5-element-support-in-javascript/

```
/*
 * isElementSupported
 * Feature test HTML element support 
 * @param {String} tag
 * @return {Boolean|Undefined}
 */

(function(win){
    'use strict';       

    var toString = {}.toString;

    win.isElementSupported = function isElementSupported(tag) {
        // Return undefined if `HTMLUnknownElement` interface
        // doesn't exist
        if (!win.HTMLUnknownElement) {
            return undefined;
        }
        // Create a test element for the tag
        var element = document.createElement(tag);
        // Check for support of custom elements registered via
        // `document.registerElement`
        if (tag.indexOf('-') > -1) {
            // Registered elements have their own constructor, while unregistered
            // ones use the `HTMLElement` or `HTMLUnknownElement` (if invalid name)
            // constructor (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28210364/1070244)
            return (
                element.constructor !== window.HTMLUnknownElement &&
                element.constructor !== window.HTMLElement
            );
        }
        // Obtain the element's internal [[Class]] property, if it doesn't 
        // match the `HTMLUnknownElement` interface than it must be supported
        return toString.call(element) !== '[object HTMLUnknownElement]';
    };

})(this);
```

Comment: This also works for `<ruby>` which is still simply `HTMLElement`. However, this function lets custom element pass, even when undefined (it will become `[object HTMLElement]`, rather HTMLUnknownElement). Nonetheless, in my latest Firefox, things like `<invalid>` always becomes `HTMLUnknownElement`.

Comment: Also, `document.createElement('x-element').constructor === HTMLElement` returns `false` in my Firefox; but `document.createElement('x-element').toString()` is indeed `"[object HTMLElement]"`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the browser support the HTMLDataListElement interface:

```
if(typeof HTMLDataListElement === 'function') {
   // your code here      
} else {
  // your code here if this feature is not supported
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should works, including elements that become `HTMLElement` rather than `HTML{Tag}Element` (like `<nav>` and `<ruby>`); and also detects [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/customElements).

```js
/**
 *
 * @param {string} tag
 */
export function tryCreateElement(tag) {
  const element = document.createElement(tag)
  const repr = element.toString()

  const output = {
    element,
    tag,
    type: 'standard',
    isValid: repr === '[object HTMLUnknownElement]' ? null : true
  }

  if (
    [
      'annotation-xml',
      'color-profile',
      'font-face',
      'font-face-src',
      'font-face-uri',
      'font-face-format',
      'font-face-name',
      'missing-glyph'
    ].includes(tag)
  ) {
    // These are not valid customElement identifiers
    // But if not defined, they will be '[object HTMLUnknownElement]', anyway.
  } else if (tag.includes('-')) {
    output.type = 'customElement'
    if (repr === '[object HTMLElement]') {
      output.isValid = false
    }
  }

  return output
}
```

`{ type: 'standard', isValid: null }` is an unsupported standard element.

About that repo in the answer, it seems that the code is simply

```js
/*
 * Feature test HTML element support
 *
 * @param {String} tag
 * @return {Boolean|Undefined}
 */
export default function isElementSupported(tag) {
    return {}.toString.call(document.createElement(tag)) !== '[object HTMLUnknownElement]';
}
```

It did work well other than that it doesn't invalidate custom elements.