# How to detect unofficial tags in html?

Tags: javascript, html

Given an HTML node, how would you tell if it bears official HTML tag or not?

```
<h9 id="someNodeId">hello<h9>
let node = document.getElementById("someNodeId");
```

In above code snippet I want `h9` is not official html tag. How do I find it out programmatically using JS?

Edit:
Preferably in `O(1)`

Comment: Using what language / toolkit?

Comment: using javascript language

Comment: Look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element

Comment: "Just remember to return true if some-tag has a - dash". Why do you say that. None of the html tags have dash.

Comment: @i_read_terms_and_services because you *can* create webComponents and registering them using JS. The only rule is that a tag **must contain a dash**. https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone already wrote a good function for this, see [usage guide on GitHub](https://github.com/ryanmorr/is-element-supported#usage).

Example:

```
isElementSupported("h1"); // true
isElementSupported("h9"); // false
```

```js
/*
 * isElementSupported
 * Feature test HTML element support 
 * @param {String} tag
 * @return {Boolean|Undefined}
 */

(function(win){
    'use strict';       

    var toString = {}.toString;

    win.isElementSupported = function isElementSupported(tag) {
        // Return undefined if `HTMLUnknownElement` interface
        // doesn't exist
        if (!win.HTMLUnknownElement) {
            return undefined;
        }
        // Create a test element for the tag
        var element = document.createElement(tag);
        // Check for support of custom elements registered via
        // `document.registerElement`
        if (tag.indexOf('-') > -1) {
            // Registered elements have their own constructor, while unregistered
            // ones use the `HTMLElement` or `HTMLUnknownElement` (if invalid name)
            // constructor (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28210364/1070244)
            return (
                element.constructor !== window.HTMLUnknownElement &&
                element.constructor !== window.HTMLElement
            );
        }
        // Obtain the element's internal [[Class]] property, if it doesn't 
        // match the `HTMLUnknownElement` interface than it must be supported
        return toString.call(element) !== '[object HTMLUnknownElement]';
    };
    
})(this);
```

```html
Tag: <input id="toCheck" type="text" value="h9"><br><br>
Is supported? <input id="result" type="text" readonly><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Check Tag" onclick="document.getElementById('result').value= (isElementSupported(document.getElementById('toCheck').value))">
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following:

```
const foo = document.createElement('h9');
console.log(foo.constructor.name); // HTMLUnknownElement
```

Note that this will not work properly for natively implemented [custom elements](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/). So barring that edge case you can easily use this method to check if a given tag is official, and unlike a hard-coded list it is future proof against new tags being added.

### Note on performance:

the above check does run in O(1) time but checking every tag in the DOM will be much, much slower.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work. If you go to angular website [here](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview) and run this `document.getElementsByTagName('MAT-EXPANSION-PANEL-HEADER')[0].constructor`, you wont get `HTMLUnknownElement`

Comment: And as far as i know, angular components are not web components.

Comment: @i_read_terms_and_services they aren't, but they won't show up in your DOM tree: Angular replaces them with regular DOM nodes. Same deal for React. They aren't real tags the way webcomponents are.

Comment: No. react and vue may do that but angular doesn't. Those unofficial tags live in DOM and you can see them

Comment: @i_read_terms_and_services angular2 maybe. I've never used it. That definitely wasn't the case for angular1 though. In any case, they still all have (or should have) hyphens, Laurens' answer looks pretty robust.

Comment: Yes. Angular1 used to do that not angular2+

Answer (score -1):

You can use `tagName` property to get the [tag name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) of the element and compare it with a list of official html tags. I found this package containing all html tags https://github.com/wooorm/html-tag-names

Comment: Please actually edit the tag list into your answer, but leave the link for attribution.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend`sanitize-html`, which is a really flexible package in `nodejs` that sanitizes input html tags. I have only used it in nodejs applications, however I think that you can include it in a browser script.

You can add it by:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="dist/sanitize-html.js"></script>
```

You can simply check whether the input HTML has changed after the sanitization, returning a boolean data type.

This is an example of sanitize-html, using the default allowed tags:

```
var sanitizeHtml = require('sanitize-html');

var dirty = 'some really tacky HTML';
var clean = sanitizeHtml(dirty);
```

You can can get a better idea by reading the official documentation: 
**https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html**

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?

Comment: By checking tags before and after the sanitization and then comparing if the content has changed.

Comment: You want to do a comparison of *the entire DOM tree serialized as a string* just to find out if a tag is legit? Plus whatever time cost (and load weight!) the sanitization library has? Does the sanitizer even strip unofficial tags?

Comment: Its not with the entire DOM tree. You pass a string of HTML tags and filters it based on the allowed tags.

Comment: According to the docs, you still have to feed it a list of the tags you'll allow. So adding the library is still entirely pointless, it's just a slower version of testing if a given tag name is in a hash or Set, and has all the fragility of that approach for when new tags get added. Plus again, the load weight of the library itself.

Answer (score -1):

I could create my own XML tags, and create a reference document that defines the schema for those tags. Since HTML, which comes from XML, has a standard schema of known tags, you can do this:

```
<h9 id='someNodeId'>Hello, world!</h9>

//list the valid tags for HTML here
let tags = ["h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6"];

let node = document.getElementById('someNodeId');
if( tags.find( node.tagName.toLowerCase() ) != undefined ) {
   //valid
}
else {
   //invalid
}
```

Comment: What does this add to the earlier answer from Alex? Also, what happens to this when they add a new tag to the spec (hint: your code breaks).