# Datalist or Select depending on browser support

Tags: javascript, php, html-datalist, browser-support

I want to use [*datalist*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp), but in case it's not supported by a browser I want do display a basic *select*. **What's the simplest way to achieve this?** I'd rather not use JavaScript (excepting simple solution without messing the code and HTML form). It could be PHP' if statement or something like *[picture tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp)*, which chooses the best available image:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="img.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="img.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
  <img src="img.jpg">
</picture>
```

I've got some solutions prepared, but I want to choose the best one. At this moment the best possible solution is to make two divs (datalist and select) and after page loading remove one div this way:

```
if ('options' in document.createElement('datalist'))
    $('#basicSelect').remove()
else
    $('#datalist').remove()
```

[Above solution was taken from this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048102/check-if-html-element-is-supported)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use JavaScript to perform [feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection). There is a chance you can fix this using the CSS `@supports` feature, but you'll have to do some cross-platform testing. However, the `<datalist>` element already has [pretty good browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist#Browser_compatibility). Is this really something you need to provide fallback support for?

Comment: According to this report it's not supported very well - https://caniuse.com/datalist. To be honest, we had quite a lot of problems with a Safari or an old Firefox, so better safe than sorry :) Thanks for advices, probably I'll use JavaScript finally if there isn't better way.

Comment: I see 95% support worlwide. How does this compare to your _actual userbase_ ? In cases like these it can be beneficial to check your own analytics. Also keep in mind the option of encouraging your users of ancient software to upgrade, instead of going out of your way to gracefully degrade everything to the 'crappiest browser'.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but at this moment every user is important for us and I know some of them are not such 'technically experienced' to update/change their browsers... :) I'll test and think about it.